# iOSアプリ継続課金(レシート検証)でサーバーがデータベースに保持すべきもの

Tags: ios, データベース設計, アプリ内課金, database, base64

iOSの継続課金のレシート検証では、
アプリ側からbase64でエンコードされたレシート情報(文字列)をサーバーが受け取り、
それをApple検証サーバーに投げてそのレスポンスを検証すると思います。

サーバーの課金バリデーションロジックが通ったら、
ユーザー情報やレシート情報(transactionIdや有効期限等)をデータベースに保持すると思います。その時、最初にアプリから受け取った生レシート(base64でエンコードされた文字列)もサーバーのデータベースに保持すべきでしょうか？

継続課金レシートのエンコードデータは課金更新されるたびに履歴が増えるのでDBに保持しても容量を取り、そもそも使用する機会はあまりないと思っていたのですが、ユーザーの課金で何か不具合があったときにその時必要な情報を参照できるように大元は残しておいたほうがよいのか、という点で保持すべきかどうかを迷っています。課金で不具合があった際に(保持しなかったことで)問題解決できないことを避けたいというのが今回の質問の背景になります。

```
// エンコードされたレシート(例)
WDGldlGDEwASAgIGrwIBAQQJAgcDjX6kGKkdkkSekgkFSkkgkdkdgkgdFSMjAxOC0wNy0yM
VowHwICBqoCAQESIgSUgaKDKgNy0yMlQwOVowggF8AgERAgEBBIIBcjGgegeGAMjAxOC0wd
E0yMFQxOToxMTo0OVowggF8AgERAgEBBIIBcjGgegeGwCwICBq0CAQEEAgwAMGaFlgdFAgB
DGdGwCwGDYCAQEEAgwAMAwCAgalAgEBBAMFCAQEwDAICBqsCAQEEAwIBAzAMAgIGrgIBAQS
QDAgEAMgEUKkkfkeolgakmMgDwDAICBrcCAQEEAwIBADASAgIGrwIBAQQJAgcDjX6nIpJnM
(以下続く)
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/137496

Comment: これは技術的な課題ではなさそうなのでコメントで、プロダクトのスコープの問題だと思います。「課金の不具合」というリスクがどのぐらいの可能性があり、またそのリスクがどれだけ「プロダクトの不利益」をもたらすかを考えるべきかなと思います。そのうえで保持するかどうか判断したほうが良さそうです。

Comment: @keitaro_so 回答ありがとうございます。確かにそのプロダクトでどこまでリスクに備えるかみたいなところですよね。1つ思いついたのが容量が重くなるレシートデータそのものを保持するよりも、Appleから返ってくるレスポンスkeyをできる限りエンティティ定義して、できる限り全てDB保持しておくほうがあとから検索するという点でもよいかもしれませんね。現在有効期限やtransactionId等 最低限必要と思われるレシート情報は保持していますが、＋＠はリスク想定に応じて追加する方向にしようかなと思います。

Comment: 質問内容としては、「保持するべきかどうか」と「保持するならばDBもしくはそれ以外の方法で容量の少ない方法」があるかに分かれると思います。「保持するべきか」は主観的な回答しか集まらないと思いますので、後半だけで質問を変更したほうが良いかもしれません。